# Razorpages: Passing a param into controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor

In my controller I have this function:

```
public ActionResult AddSubSub(int? idOfSubsub)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { searchword = "" });
}
```

I can call this function, but never give the param.

I tried:

```
        function AddSubSub(idOfSubsub) {
            $('#mainForm').dirtyForms('setClean');
            var mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
            mainForm.action = '@Url.Action("AddSubSub", "idOfSubsub", new { idOfSubsub = 2 });';
            mainForm.submit();
        }
```

But this fails stating it cannot find the url. If done without the param it works.

Can you help me out here?
Also I have not found out how to pass the js param (idOfSubsub) into the c# code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Also I have not found out how to pass the js param (idOfSubsub) into the c# code.

You can try to set mainForm.action without using `@Url.Action`:

```
function AddSubSub(idOfSubsub) {
            $('#mainForm').dirtyForms('setClean');
            var mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
            mainForm.action = '/idOfSubsub/AddSubSub?idOfSubsub='+idOfSubsub;
            mainForm.submit();
        }
```

Then the mainForm will be submitted to `AddSubSub` action in `idOfSubsub` controller.

Comment: unfortunately, this will resolve in my function not being found

Comment: What is the route of your action?What is the controller name?